# Assign return type to a reference, does a copy take place?

Tags: c++, reference

Does a copy still take place here:

```
std::vector<int> &f = foo();
```

where `foo`'s prototype is

```
std::vector<int> foo();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`foo()` returns a temporary object which cannot be bound to *non-const* reference.

Do one of these:

```
//temporary can be bound to const-reference, so this is ok
const std::vector<int> &f = foo();  //no copy takes place.

//or save a copy of temporary
std::vector<int> f = foo(); //copy takes place (may be optimized by compiler)
```

Read the comments above. In the second version (non-reference version), the compiler may optimize the return value, avoiding the copying of temporary. It depends on the implementation of `foo()` as well.

See this:

- [Return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Comment: for those examples, does a copy still take place?

Comment: @pingu - the compiler is very likely but not guaranteed to optimize away the copy in the second version - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Comment: Modern (C++11) compilers will _move_ the vector in the second example. (Essentially a shallow copy) saving you 99% of the cost of the deep copy.

Answer (score 2):

You're code isn't legal.  It should be either:

```
std::vector<int> const& f = foo();
```

or

```
std::vector<int> f = foo();
```

The standard allows a copy in both cases (at least C++03 did—I 
think C++11 tighted things up in the first case); it requires it in
neither, and I don't know of a compiler which actually does a copy in
either case.  If you're really worried about the copy, though, changing
the declaration of `foo` to:

```
void foo( std::vector<int>& results );
```

and using:

```
std::vector<int> f;
foo( f );
```

guarantees that there will be no copies, anywhere.  It's not as pretty,
but if profiling shows that copying is a bottleneck here, it should be
considered.

Comment: Thanks James, would i be right in saying the only other option to avoid a copy would be to use a smart pointer?

Comment: C++03 compiers may not be able to use RVO depending on the internals of the function.  I've heard many compilers stumble with things like http://codepad.org/n88KlNFc

Comment: @pingu: you could also pass a vector by reference to the function to put the return value into.

Comment: @pingu A smart pointer could be used, but that introduces more complexity than is needed.  And an additional dynamic allocation: the containers in the standard library are designed so that we (the users) don't have to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: @MooingDuck RVO isn't the issue here.  Whether RVO is used will depend on the contents of the function.  The issue here is whether the compiler merges the temporary used to hold the return value with the local variable at the call site.  (RVO is whether the compiler merges objects---named or not---in the function with the temporary used to hold the return value.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: You said `I don't know of a compiler which actually does a copy in either case.`  I've heard that our compilers can't do that to some functions, in which case they must copy.  Also, I can't think of a case where a function returns a value that wasn't a named or unnamed object in the function.  Ergo, that's all RVO.

Comment: @MooingDuck In all of the literature I've seen, RVO is an optimization in the function returning the value, not at the call site.  The optimization at the call site is independent of what the called function does.

Comment: @JamesKanze: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization "The term return value optimization refers to a special clause in the C++ standard that allows an implementation to omit a copy operation resulting from a return statement"  RVO is _only_ the copy, not the merging of returns.

Comment: @MooingDuck So the Wikipedia invents its own definition, and uses the term differently that it was used in the discussions in the standards committee.  (In the end, it's only a question of vocabulary.  But I find it useful to distinguish between the two copies.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I cannot speak as to the discussions of the standards committee.  § 12.8\32 says both are allowed, but you're right that they're listed as two separate optimizations, and nowhere is "RVO" used.   Judging by the wording though, I must infer that you were right, and RVO probably only refers to the in-function part.